# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I am attempting to write custom HTML to SweetAlert2, the code I am attempting to make has the user input a bot name then submit it to our API.

The code works fine on Windows, however when I do this on Chrome MacOS I get the error  `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`. The placeholder also does not register on MacOS, this all works fine on Chrome Windows though.
[Image of the placeholder not registering.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPQsR.png)
[Submission Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMmP4.png)

I believe it has to do with the HTML not registering on Chrome Mac because I took a look within the developer console and found it to not be showing the placeholder or ID at all.
[Developer Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGNUZ.png)

Original HTML:

```html
<a class="button w-button is-link is-light" style="min-height: 0px;border-width: 1px;cursor: pointer;justify-content: center;padding-bottom: .5em;padding-left: 2em;padding-right: 2em;padding-top: calc(.6em - 2px);text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;" target="_blank" id="change-name">Change Bot Name</a>
```

Sweetalert JS:

```js
// Update Bot Name:
$(function() {
  $('#change-name').click(function() {
      Swal.fire({
          html: `<br><b>Update Bot Name</b><br><input type="text" id="newbotname" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Enter the new name for your bot.">`,
          confirmButtonText: 'Update',
          showCancelButton: true,
          focusConfirm: false,
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          reverseButtons: true,
          preConfirm: () => {
            const NewBotName = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#newbotname').value
            if (!NewBotName) {
              Swal.showValidationMessage(`Please ensure that you have entered a new bot name!`)
            }
            return { NewBotName: NewBotName }
          }
        }).then((result) => {
          $.post("/service/bots/general/update/name",
          {
            NewBotName: `${result.value.NewBotName}`
          },
          function(data, status){
            if (data.success == true) {
              Swal.fire(
                'Updated!',
                'Your bot name has been updated.',
                'success'
              )
            } else {
              Swal.fire(
                'Oops!',
                'There was an error updating your bot name.',
                'error'
              )
            }
          });
          
      })
  })
});
```

I tried reading up on other answers about this but could not find one that resolves this, especially it not rendering the HTML properly such as the placeholder.

Comment: rather than `.getPopup` - which does not appear in the docs, I think you mean `getContainer`

Comment: @RandyCasburn No luck, I get the same error and the placeholder still doesn't appear.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with Sweetalert itself. Reverting to 11.3.1 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this was the issue in v11.3.2, please upgrade to v11.3.3.

---

The problem with your code is that you're trying to imitate manually the build-in functionality with input.

Instead of doing this

```js
Swal.fire({
  html: `<br><b>Update Bot Name</b><br><input type="text" id="newbotname" class="swal2-input" placeholder="Enter the new name for your bot.">`,
  preConfirm: () => {
    const NewBotName = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#newbotname').value
    if (!NewBotName) {
      ...         
})
```

Do what the documentation suggests you:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Update Bot Name',
  input: 'text',
  inputPlaceholder: 'Enter the new name for your bot'
  preConfirm: (NewBotName) => {
    if (!NewBotName) {    
      ...      
})
```